# T-SQL View to retrieve both of the lookups in one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

I'm no SQL expert so excuse if my question sounds silly.

I have a Multi-Lookup table:

ID ProID AmID

The ID is an identity column and auto-generates the ID on insert. The ProID and the AmID links to a Candidate table, on the ID column in that.

I need to create a View that will return the Firstname Lastname AS Pro and Firstname Lastname AS Am in a single view, along with the ID from the Candidate table.

```
ID Pro            ProID Am            AmID
1  Name Surname   1     Name Surname  2
2  Name Surname   3     Name Surname  78
etc
```

I created two separate select statements for both the pro and the am candidate, but don't know how to merge them into a single statement?

```
SELECT  T2.[ID], 
        T2.[Firstname] + ' ' + T2.[Lastname] AS 'Pro'      
FROM [Teams] AS T1
INNER JOIN [Candidate] AS T2
    ON T1.ProID = T2.ID

SELECT  T2.[ID], 
        T2.[Firstname] + ' ' + T2.[Lastname] AS 'Am'       
FROM [Teams] AS T1
INNER JOIN [Candidate] AS T2
    ON T1.AmID = T2.ID
```

I looked this up, and it seems that I would need to do a RIGHT JOIN on this, but it screws up the results.

Is this scenario possible, or will I have to settle for two distinct calls to the SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to basically join the table `Candidate` on your `Teams` table twice so you can get the equivalent value for each column.

```
SELECT  a.ID, b.ProID, c.AmID, 
        b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName as ProName, 
        c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as AmName   
FROM    Teams a
        INNER JOIN candidate b
            ON a.ProID = b.ID
        INNER JOIN candidate c
            ON a.AmID = c.ID
```

If one of the columns is *nullable*, `LEFT JOIN` is needed than `INNER JOIN` so non-matching values will still be on the list of result.

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

To create `VIEW`

```
CREATE VIEW viewName
AS
    SELECT  a.ID, b.ProID, c.AmID, 
            b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName as ProName, 
            c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as AmName   
    FROM    Teams a
            INNER JOIN candidate b
                ON a.ProID = b.ID
            INNER JOIN candidate c
                ON a.AmID = c.ID
```

- [TSQL View](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7143.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `UNION` to get all your results:

```
SELECT 
   C.Id, 
   C.FIrstName + ' ' + C.LastName as Pro,
   'Pro' Type
FROM Teams T
   JOIN Candidates C ON T.ProdId = C.Id
UNION
SELECT 
   C.Id, 
   C.FIrstName + ' ' + C.LastName as Am,
   'Am' Type
FROM Teams T
   JOIN Candidates C ON T.AmId = C.Id
```

If you want them in separate columns, then this should work:

```
SELECT 
       C.Id as ProdId, 
       C.FIrstName + ' ' + C.LastName as Pro,
       C2.Id as AmId,
       C2.FIrstName + ' ' + C2.LastName as Am
    FROM Teams T
       JOIN Candidates C ON T.ProdId = C.Id
       JOIN Candidates2 C ON T.AmId = C.Id
```

Final note, depending on your RDBMS, if you need a counter as in your first column, look into using ROW_NUMBER() for SQL Server or Oracle, or declaring your own variable for MySQL.

Good luck.